# Running an infinite java program and how performance is affected

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, infinite-loop

So im not much of a thread expert, nor java for that matter.

Okay so I made a little program that runs infinite.. (its supposed to)

Get data from XML file every minute and prints it. The xml updates every couple of seconds, but only want the 1 minute print.
So my main looks something like this.

```
while(true) {
   try {
       Thread.sleep(60000);
       String data = getSomeDataFromXMLFile();
       System.out.println(data);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

The code works how its supposed to. Just wanting to know if it can affect my servers performance in any way? Like after 10 days of running it hogs all RAM or something..

Suggestions and improvements are very welcome.

Comment: TimerTask might be better suited for this kind of feature, but I don't see any problems with your current solution.

Comment: It all depends whether you have some memory leaks in your application...

Comment: this code does not hint to leak. Post whole code.

Comment: It depends on what `getSomeDataFromXMLFile` does. Also note that as long as you stay within a method, there is no guarantee that the GC will run.

Comment: It extracts data from an xml file, using javax.xml.parsers and w3c.dom* packages.. So knowing this, can I be unfortunate that the GC wont run ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what I did last week, I built something that runs an infinite loop and does some transactions. I noticed that there will be no problem if:

1. Each thread who run will finish its transaction. Because if not, it will stay alive and your program will continue to create thread until your JVM will not be able to hold a thread anymore.
2. If there is [a memory leak](http://plumbr.eu/blog/what-is-a-memory-leak), some objects that your JVM will not be able to clear.

Comment: I see, thanks for the link ill brush up on memory leaks right away :)

Comment: +1 if you see a problem it will be due to a bug in your code. there is no particular reason it cannot run for years continuously.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that `getSomeDataFromXMLFile()` is correct (does not leak memory), your code is fine. Maybe not beautiful, but fine.

One small unrelated improvement - if you want to read a file every minute (as opposed to: sleep for a minute between each read) you'll have to take the time of `getSomeDataFromXMLFile()` into account.

Consider [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class to shrink your code a bit and avoid the problem above:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String data = getSomeDataFromXMLFile();
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}, 0, 60000);
```

Comment: Shrink?  You code has one more source line and no exception handler.

Comment: @MartinJames: well, not literally. Shrink in terms of complexity. No extra threads (notice that OP is probably using `main`, but typically that's not the case), `InterruptedException` doesn't have to be handled as well, irrelevant `sleep()` is no longer there. But in a way - my code is more complex as it uses more sophisticated structures, +1.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does not contain a memory leak. In Java you do not usually need to explicitly free memory resources because it uses automatic [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). When you assign to `data` the old value is no longer referenced and becomes eligible for garbage collection. It will be automatically freed when the garbage collector next runs. The garbage collector will run as needed - you don't need to tell it to run explicitly.

However you should be careful to ensure that you close any resources such as file handles inside the `getSomeDataFromXMLFile` method.

Answer (score 1):

> Like after 10 days of running it hogs all RAM or something?

It depends on how `getSomeDataFromXMLFile()` is imlemented.

If you are sure, that methods is as optimized as possible. it's won't affect server at all.

Answer (score 0):

these will not hog over RAM for sure, as you are assigning to same data object, old data object's memory will be reclaimed by garbage collector when needed. Also if you are having multiple threads, debug whether threads are dying when they should, if not dying you have great problem, and threads will hog RAM, which can cause heap shortage.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted is ok. I've seen even a much lower time interval infinite loops without problems, and it all depends on how you manage the recourses in the getSomeDataFromXML() method.

Anyway, you can check for watch directory for changes that Java 7 has available: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html
that way it will only runs when the XML changes.